# Change itemize margin

Tags: spacing, pdftex, itemize

I am working inside the beamer environement and need to change the margin width for an itemize enveronement.
The only way i found to do this is shown below.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.1\linewidth}
\hspace*{5pt}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Doel] Dimensioneren ventilatiesysteem
    \item[Strategie] Berekening vereenvoudigen \\ Keuzes bieden
    \item[Status] Berekening in orde
    \item[Uitwerking]   Dimensioneren\\
                        Weergeven\\
                        Keuze bieden
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

This gives the right result but i don't think it is the right way to do it.

[image: Result]

How do i do it a more TeXy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{description}
    \item[Doel] Dimensioneren ventilatiesysteem
    \item[Strategie] Berekening vereenvoudigen \\ Keuzes bieden
    \item[Status] Berekening in orde
    \item[Uitwerking]   Dimensioneren\\
                        Weergeven\\
                        Keuze bieden
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```